# Minify/compress javascript and css on deployment in webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, compression, minify, webapp2

Is it possible to make App Engine automatically minify certain javascript and css files upon deployment, just like Jinja2 automatically compiles templates for you? I've seen some Python scripts that do minification, but how do I integrate them with webapp2?

I'm using the latest Google App Engine version with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple script to do so.

```
# -- update_batch.py --
import sys
import os

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        return 

    appId = sys.argv[1]
    print "appId", appId

    # Your script to minify javascipt
    #os.chdir(r".\template")
    #cmd = r'jscom.py ./js/new/xxx_plugin.js xxx_plugin.js %s.appspot.com'%appId
    #os.system(cmd)

    os.chdir("..")
    # Perform appcfg.py to update GAE server
    cmd = r'"C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py"'
    os.system(cmd + " update . " + " -A %s"%appId)

    #os.system(cmd + " backends . " + " update worker " + " -A %s"%appId)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# Usage update_batch.py YOUR_APP_ID_HERE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would it be possible to hook a script like this directly into a webapp2 app so I don't have to call a separate script for deployment but can deploy as I normally would using the Google App Engine Launcher?

Comment: @Aneon This has nothing to do with the webapp framework you use - that's not involved in the deploy process in any way. And no, there's no way to run a pre-deploy script from appcfg.

Comment: Ah, I assumed Jinja2 ran a pre-compile script for its templates, but I guess it's done some other way. Thanks.